# Post not built with Jekyll

Tags: static, jekyll, blogs

I just started with Jekyll and tried to create a new post, and then I ran the command

```
jekyll build
```

But it didn't work, this didn't create my new post in the _site/update/2015/12/24 folder.

I didn't change anything before starting using Jekyll.

Would you have any ideas?

Thank !

Comment: Can you give some more hints, like posts file name, post code, and why not a github repository url.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you used `jekyll new NAME` to generate a default jekyll blog and did not change a file structure nor names inside of it.

Have you created your post in the `_posts` folder?

Does your post have a `html` or `md` extension?

Did you add a front matter to your post?

Did you name your blog post according to [jekyll documentation](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/posts/)?

Did you run `jekyll build` from a root folder of your jekyll blog?

Comment: Sorry for the delay I didn't have any connection the last past days. Actually this morning, my second post was displayed and I tried to add one more which was displayed also. I don't know what happened, probably just a glitch...